# VBA to copy specific cells from one worksheet to another upon meeting a criteria

Tags: excel, vba, copy, copy-paste

My VBA knowledge is very limited, so looking for some help here. Tried some Googling and putting together a code but hasn't met the goal. Appreciate the help here!

I have 2 worksheets:

1. Data - source worksheet with the data to be copied
2. Dashboard - Target sheet for pasting

Data sheet - It has multiple columns, the ones I have named are the ones I need to be copied except the column named "Sold?" which is for criteria. The other columns with no names in the image actually have data, to avoid confusion I have removed them here.
This sheet grows and I will add a new row of data when needed.
[image: Data sheet]

Dashboard Sheet - When I click "Refresh" button, I want the code to check the "Data" sheet and if a row meets of criteria of Sold? = "N", then only data from column C,G,J,M should be copied and pasted into columns B,C,D,E of "Dashboard" sheet. Additional criteria: if an investment name repeats, the details need to be summed up and shown in Dashboard sheet. I have provided my expected output in the image. (ABC & TY summed up)

[image]

I have tried a bit but unable to incorporate all the criteria and this code when run doesn't throw an error but does nothing, no output.

```
Private Sub Refresh_Click()

Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

a = Worksheets("Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 12 To a
If Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 15).Value = "N" Then
Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 3).Copy
Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 7).Copy
Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 13).Copy
Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 14).Copy

Worksheets("Dashboard").Activate
Worksheets("Dashboard").Range("B6:G25").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If
Next

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not a [pivot table](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UsdedFoTA68)? Anyway: a problem in your code is your use of Range.Copy . Right now the code will only copy the last cell (the 14th column's one). You have to copy all the cells at once.

Comment: You do not need vba coding here.  pivot table is your solution as Evil Blue Monkey mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Yes, I did consider Pivot table but the "Data" sheet I have mentioned here, I have a few similar sheets (same format) but with different data. Pivot table for each sheet makes the file bulky. So, thought of having a code that can be replicated across sheets to pull in values and display in the "Dashboard" sheet. Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest a pivot table. Still if you want VBA based solution, you might try this code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Refresh_Click()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim BlnHiddenColumns() As Boolean
    Dim DblFirstRow As Double
    Dim DblLastRow As Double
    Dim DblCounter01 As Double
    Dim DblCounterLimit01 As Double
    Dim DblInvestmentNameColumn As Double
    Dim DblQuantityColumn As Double
    Dim DblAfterChargeColumn As Double
    Dim DblCurrentPLColumn As Double
    Dim DblSoldColumn As Double
    Dim RngData As Range
    Dim RngResult As Range
    Dim StrAutofilterAddress As String
    Dim StrMarker As String
    Dim StrInvestmentNameHeader As String
    Dim StrQuantityHeader As String
    Dim StrAfterChargeHeader As String
    Dim StrCurrentPLHeader As String
    Dim WksData As Worksheet
    Dim WksDashboard As Worksheet
    Dim WksPivotTable As Worksheet
    Dim PvtPivotTable01 As PivotTable
    
    'Settings.
    DblInvestmentNameColumn = 3
    DblQuantityColumn = 7
    DblAfterChargeColumn = 10
    DblCurrentPLColumn = 13
    DblSoldColumn = 15
    DblFirstRow = 12
    DblCounterLimit01 = 1000
    StrMarker = "N"
    Set WksData = Worksheets("Data")
    DblLastRow = WksData.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set RngData = WksData.Range(WksData.Cells(DblFirstRow - 1, Excel.WorksheetFunction.Min(DblInvestmentNameColumn, DblQuantityColumn, DblAfterChargeColumn, DblCurrentPLColumn, DblSoldColumn)), WksData.Cells(DblLastRow, Excel.WorksheetFunction.Max(DblInvestmentNameColumn, DblQuantityColumn, DblAfterChargeColumn, DblCurrentPLColumn, DblSoldColumn)))
    ReDim BlnHiddenColumns(1 To RngData.Columns.Count)
    Set WksDashboard = Worksheets("Dashboard")
    Set RngResult = WksDashboard.Range("B6")
    StrInvestmentNameHeader = WksDashboard.Range("B5").Value
    StrQuantityHeader = WksDashboard.Range("C5").Value
    StrAfterChargeHeader = WksDashboard.Range("D5").Value
    StrCurrentPLHeader = WksDashboard.Range("E5").Value
    
    'Turning off screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Checking for any previous results list.
    If Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(RngResult) <> RngResult.Cells.Count Then
        DblCounter01 = 0
        
        'Checking each row of the result list until an entirely blank row is found.
        Do Until Excel.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(RngResult.Offset(DblCounter01, 0)) = RngResult.Cells.Count
            
            DblCounter01 = DblCounter01 + 1
            
            'If the number of rows checked is equal or superior to DblCounterLimit01 the macro is terminated.
            If DblCounter01 >= DblCounterLimit01 Then
                MsgBox "Please clear the current holdings list manually", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Unable to clear the current list"
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
        Loop
        
        'Clearing the list.
        RngResult.Parent.Range(RngResult, RngResult.Offset(DblCounter01 - 1)).ClearContents
        
    End If
    
    'Checking for existing autofilter in WksData.
    If WksData.AutoFilterMode = True Then
        'Coping the address of the autofilter in WksData.
        StrAutofilterAddress = WksData.AutoFilter.Range.Address
    End If
    
    'Removing any autofilter in WksData.
    WksData.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    'Covering each column of RngData.
    For DblCounter01 = 1 To RngData.Columns.Count
        
        'Setting BlnHiddenColumns accordingly to the RngData columns' status (hidden/not hidden).
        BlnHiddenColumns(DblCounter01) = RngData.Columns(DblCounter01).Hidden
        
        'Hiding the columns of RngData we won't copy.
        Select Case DblCounter01 + RngData.Column - 1
            Case Is = DblInvestmentNameColumn, DblQuantityColumn, DblAfterChargeColumn, DblCurrentPLColumn
                RngData.Columns(DblCounter01).Hidden = False
            Case Else
                RngData.Columns(DblCounter01).Hidden = True
        End Select
    Next
    
    'Filtering RngData.
    RngData.AutoFilter Field:=DblSoldColumn - RngData.Column + 1, Criteria1:=StrMarker
    
    'Copying the filtered RngData into RngResult.
    RngData.Resize(RngData.Rows.Count - 1, RngData.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy RngResult
    
    'Restoring the RngData columns to their previous status (hidden/not hidden).
    For DblCounter01 = 1 To RngData.Columns.Count
        If BlnHiddenColumns(DblCounter01) Then
            RngData.Columns(DblCounter01).Hidden = True
        Else
            RngData.Columns(DblCounter01).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
    
    'Removing any autofilter in WksData.
    WksData.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    'Restoring any pre-existing autofilter in WksData.
    If StrAutofilterAddress <> "" Then
        WksData.Range(StrAutofilterAddress).AutoFilter
    End If
    
    'Setting RngResult to cover the imported list (headers included).
    Set RngResult = RngResult.Offset(-1, 0)
    Set RngResult = WksDashboard.Range(RngResult, RngResult.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight))
    
    'Creating WksPivotTable.
    Set WksPivotTable = Sheets.Add
    
    'Creating PvtPivotTable01.
    Set PvtPivotTable01 = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                                            SourceData:=RngResult, _
                                                            Version:=7 _
                                                           ).CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=WksPivotTable.Cells(1, 1), _
                                                                              TableName:="Temporary Pivot Table", _
                                                                              DefaultVersion:=7 _
                                                                             )
    
    'Setting PvtPivotTable01.
    With PvtPivotTable01.PivotFields(StrInvestmentNameHeader)
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With PvtPivotTable01
        .AddDataField .PivotFields(StrQuantityHeader), "Sum of " & StrQuantityHeader, xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields(StrAfterChargeHeader), "Sum of " & StrAfterChargeHeader, xlSum
        .AddDataField .PivotFields(StrCurrentPLHeader), "Sum of " & StrCurrentPLHeader, xlSum
        .ColumnGrand = False
    End With
    
    'Clearing the data from RngResult.
    RngResult.Offset(1, 0).Resize(RngResult.Rows.Count - 1).ClearContents
    
    'Copying the PvtPivotTable01 content to RngResult.
    PvtPivotTable01.DataBodyRange.Offset(0, -1).Resize(, PvtPivotTable01.DataFields.Count + 1).Copy RngResult.Cells(2, 1)
    
    'Deleting WksPivotTable.
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WksPivotTable.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    'Restoring screen updating.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
End Sub
```

I've intentionally made it longer than the necessary, especially by creating many variables to avoid hard coded data. This method might be useful in more complex and/or longer codes.

Comment: Thanks for the code. I tried applying this inside the "Refresh" command button and tried to run it but nothing happened. The Dashboard sheet stays blank. No error is given. Any thoughts?

Comment: This is strange. I've added an opening message at the very beginning of the macro. If the macro is correcly called, it will appear. If nothing happens, the button is not correctly linked to the macro. Try the code and send feedback, please.

Comment: Figured out what went wrong. The last row check in data sheet was happening on Column A which is actually fully blank always (more of a border), so changed it to column B and the code works.

Comment: A couple of issues though:
1. The code takes nearly 15-20 secs to run and Excel goes to unresponsive stage. If I were to extend this code to fetch data from multiple sheets, it might not be so smooth. Any way to optimize the code?
2. Right now, it just fetches the data as is from the data sheet but it is not summing them up on the Investment name. Could this be added?

Comment: 1) Considering that you have an actual column that marks the data you need, we might order the list (or just filter it) and copy the whole section we need. That should make the code faster i think. Then again: a pivot table still should be the best solution. 2) I totally forgot about the summing part. It can be added.

Comment: Would you be able to modify the code to handle those as well? @Evil Blue Monkey

Comment: Now that i think about it: since i'm using a pivot table anyway, it would be way more obvious to use it directly on the Data sheet...